# How to pass my mongoose session to another service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Setting

I'm building an app using microservice architecture.
I need at some point to pass a mongoose session (and its transaction) to another microservice.
Thus, if a single error happens in one microservice, I can rollback all the changes made by all the microservices.

#### What I tried

##### Sending ClientSession

I first tried to send directly ClientSession object to my microservice.
However, since ClientSession is not serializable, I cannot send it properly.
Received error:

```
ERROR   HttpError [InternalServerError]: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle
```

##### Sending Transaction

I then tried to send transaction started by my session in microservice A and to attach it to a freshly created session on microservice B.

Microservice A:

```js
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
mongoose.startTransaction();

const { transaction } = session;

try {
  await callMicroserviceB(transaction);
  await session.commitTransaction();
} catch (e) {
  await session.abortTransaction();
} finally {
  await session.endSession();
}
```

Microservice B:

```js
const { transaction } = event;

const session =  await mongoose.startSession();
session.transaction = transaction;

... // Microservice code

await session.endSession();
```

When performing any query on a Model, I receive the following error:

```
Error: session.transaction.transition is not a function
```

Is there a way to share a ClientSession or a Transaction?

Comment: why don't you let the lambda handling the session itself?

Comment: Because I need to use the same session/transaction in order to invalidate all the chain if a single error happens

Comment: @wakobu were you able to get this resolved? If yes, please share how you accomplished this as I’m currently stuck on how to approach this the right way.